# Mootools extension Behavior throwing error

Tags: javascript, mootools

since there is no guide to integrate this Mootools extension / plugin, I thought about including the scripts...

This should looks like this:

```
//standart
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/mootools.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/mootools.more.js"></script>

//addons        
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/behavior/Source/BehaviorAPI.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/behavior/Source/Behavior.js"></script>

//Here should be all the magic called...
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

But trying to call the website, it prints out into the console:

```
>>ReferenceError: Table is not defined
this._cleanupFunctions = new Table();<<
```

It seems that 'Table' is a Class writting in the extension 'More' but it seems not to exist...

Anyone having a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact it seems that `Table` does not exist as class. Are you sure if your more.js contains that class ? There are two points you have to check:

1. This class only exists with mootools more 1.4. It did not exist before.
2. When you download, you can [create a custom build](http://mootools.net/more/) that only contains the classes you select and their dependencies. Probably your build does not include all classes. Redownload it and check `Table` to include it.

Comment: Okay my bad, I had to update CORE aswell. Works finally ty! :)

Answer (score 2):

if you open your mootools-more.js file, it will have a url for the saved hash build. it will look like this:

http://mootools.net/more/09f3e47813269cd5026cbf8c1f828e72

visit the url (yours) then also add `Table` and any other deps you may have to and re-download, then replace your script.

Answer (score 2):

You may be calling it before Mooltools has loaded. Wait for the dom to load first:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
    this._cleanupFunctions = new Table();
});
```